# MasterDetailRenderer is not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Error coming from MasterDetailRenderer. Application crash when I use MasterDetailsRenderer.

I have created one MasterPage (it is default master page) on Portable.

Now I want to change width of Details section on Android application. So, I am doing like in android application.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage), typeof(MasterPageRnD.DemoPage))]
namespace MasterPageRnD.Droid
{
    public class MasterDetailRenderers : MasterDetailRenderer
    {

    }
}
```

Also I have changed this line

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```

Default was like

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

In MainActivity.

What is wrong ?
Anyone facing this type of error ?

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage), typeof(MasterDetailRenderers ))]
```